# WebBrowser, right click on links to open new tab

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have made this code to open new TABs, if I click "right click" on links then I choose "open in new window"

it's open a new TAB in my browser but at the same time Internet Explorer will be opened too.

**I just want to make the IE silent, or making new tab option not gray to use it. I don't want to make my custom menu, I am sure there is a solution for this.**

I have searched on my question here it's different problem so please it's not duplicate

This is what I have used to make that works

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow1(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
        Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.
It's simple this command line will make IE silent.

```
e.Cancel = True
```

You don't need to build other menu and turn off the main menu of the IE then build all Items again.

This is the final code to open links when you click "right click on them" and will be opened in a new tab

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow1(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
   e.Cancel = True

    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href")
    With Browser
        .Navigate(targeturl)
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End With

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(targeturl)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
    AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
    int = int + 1

End Sub
```